# How to determine apps installed on Android device?

Tags: android

is there a way to determine what apps are currently installed on an android device? I guess reading /data/app directory doesn't do the trick (access denied)
thanks in advance for your help
regards
peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [PackageManager.getInstalledApplications()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications%28int%29)